# Why the crest of water absorb more light than the trough of water?

Tags: visible-light, waves, absorption

I have done my experiment using water ripple to study the behavior of waves. I know that the crest will absorb more light than the trough so that the image created on the white paper sheet appeared to be the troughs has darker lines than the crests. However now I wonder why the crest of water absorb more light than the trough?

Comment: As LDC3 mentioned, it's basically optics. The crests act like a magnifying glass which makes bright spots, whereas the troughs defocus the light making dark spots.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the peaks and valleys of the waves absorbs the same amount of light. What appears as light and dark band are the refraction of light from the peaks and valleys. 
[image: Light shines on water]

The light that strikes near the crest of the waves are focused together to create a bright spot and the light that strikes near the valley of the waves are dispersed.

Comment: +1 Good answer: a nitpick: dispersed is not a good word in the last sentence: suggest "defocussed", "caused to diverge", or "spread apart".

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance How about one of these synonyms: scatter, disseminate, distribute, spread, broadcast

Comment: "spread"/"spread appart" seems good.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? Trough absorbs least light and crest absorbs maximum. Hence asper law of reflection trough is brighter than crest in water wave.